# Mix up of two domains in search result

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, google-search

I would like to know why my two domains are mixed up in the search result. The two domains are `https://vym.io` and `https://remotebase.io`.

When I search 'remotebase', I see the title, and description of `remotebase.io` in the result, but it links to `vym.io`.

This is very strange because nowhere in the codebase of `vym.io` can I find any mention about remotebase. I also did a global search for 'vym' in `remotebase.io's` code and could not find anything.

In the Google Wwebmasters Tool's Search Analytics page for `vym.io`, I see all kinds of keywords related to `remotebase.io` but has nothing to do with `vym.io`. Also, in Google Analytics for RemoteBase, I can see links to `vym.io` showing up in the referrals.

Thing I have tried:

1. Three days ago, I removed DNS settings for `vym.io` so that it does not resolve. This did not work and I restored the DNS.
2. I compared `<meta name="google-site-verification" ...>` tag for both websites, and they are using different keys.

Additional info:

- The websites are associated with different properties on google analytics.

I am out of ideas and this is very frustrating. Please help.

**Edit**

When I google `site:vym.io`, I get all the pages that belong to `remotebase.io`.

[image]

But when I click on them I go to `vym.io` and there is nothing on the page because the routes belong to `remotebase.io`.

#### Edit 2

These are nginx configs for each websites, hosted on separate servers.

*remotebase.conf*

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''  close;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  server_name remotebase.io;
  return 301 https://remotebase.io$request_uri;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/remotebase-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/remoteabse-error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  }

  server_name www.remotebase.io;
  return 301 $scheme://remotebase.io$request_uri;
}
```

*vym.conf*

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''  close;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name vym.io;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/vym.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/vym.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }

  server_name www.vym.io;
  return 301 $scheme://vym.io$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: What do you see when you use Fetch as Google? Are there any crawl errors? You should be seeing what the Googlebot sees and will get indexed. From a cursory check on some of the URLs returned, there appears to be some redirect errors occurring. I'd check your _vhost_ and _.htaccess_, which might help if you edit into the question.

Comment: @dan I fetched and rendered as Google and I can see both sites fine. Could you point me to the redirect error? Also I edited the question to included nginx config I am using.

Comment: @dan FYI I moved remotebase.io to a new server to see what happens. Will this help?

Comment: Also I took down the app running on vym.io and deleted DNS settings for vym.io. It now does not resolve. This is fine because I only need to get remotebase.io to work.

Comment: @dan I removed https://vym.io/ from google using search console yesterday, and now search queries 'site:remotebase.io' or 'remotebase' do not return https://remotebase.io in the result. The query 'remotebase.io' still returns a site with vym.io's meta tags but the correct link. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, the things you did would help. I only see `remotebase.io` URLs that lead to `remotebase.io` content being returned by `site:remotebase.io` and Google Search for `remotebase.io`. I don't see `vym.io` URLs being returned, and I only see one mention of `Vym` in the results on the second and fourth result pages. You can ask Google to [remove](https://support.google.com/websearch/troubleshooter/3111061?hl=en#ts=2889054%2C2889060) those, though it should update after the next crawl. The indexed pages for `vym.io` will also be removed by Google eventually, though shouldn't impact anything.

Comment: Since this seems to be resolved, to close it out you could answer the question below with what you did above so it might be helpful to others (or delete the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I still do not know why it happened, I resolved the issue by moving remotebase.io to a new server. It took around 24 hours for the change to take affect.

I also removed vym.io from Google using webmaster tools. I do not know for sure if doing so helped at all.